# Wildcard and non-wildcard DNS records

Tags: dns

I would like to direct anyone who goes to app.mydomain.com to 1.2.3.4 and anyone who goes to *.app.mydomain.com to 9.9.9.9.

I've set up these exact two records but when I go to app.mydomain.com I get to 9.9.9.9.

Is it possible to set up these records that way?

Comment: How are you currently trying to achieve that? Are you setting your own DNS server? If so, which is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ORIGIN app.mydomain.com.
@ IN A 1.2.3.4
* IN A 9.9.9.9
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation? Did you test it? On which DNS server and version?

Comment: This is BIND syntax, works with any version.

Comment: This information is not for me. I know BIND relatively well. Good quality answers on Stack Exchange have some explanation. Your answers is not certainly good from this point of view. If you want to make it better please edit it. (The answer should not be scattered over comments.)

Comment: Not sure what kind of explanation you are looking for. The question is about what RR:s to add to achieve a specific result. The answer is quite simple and does not require an explanation.